# NSToolbarItems removing gives constraint error

Tags: macos, cocoa, constraints, nstoolbar, nstoolbaritem

I have a NSToolBar with few toolbar items in it. I added this toolbar and items in xib file.
In a specific situation I want to add another new toolbar item and remove it again when I complete the task related to it.

I am able to do this, but with removing of the tool bar item, I am getting constraints related warnings. I dont want this warnings. CAn you please help me where I am going wrong?

Here is my code to remove toolbar item from toolbar:

```
-(void)removeFullVersionButton
{
    [self.toolbarItems removeObjectAtIndex:[self.toolbarItems indexOfObject:TOOLBAR_ITEM_IDENTIFIER] -1];

    [self.toolbarItems removeObject:TOOLBAR_ITEM_IDENTIFIER];
    [self.toolbarItemDictionary removeObjectForKey:TOOLBAR_ITEM_IDENTIFIER];

    [self.toolbar removeItemAtIndex:self.toolbar.items.count-2];
    [self.toolbar removeItemAtIndex:self.toolbar.items.count-3];
}
```

I am getting this warning:

2014-01-17 17:22:58.804 UK Car Driving Theory Test Lite[14193:303] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints:
(
    "",
    "",
    ""
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint

Set the NSUserDefault NSConstraintBasedLayoutVisualizeMutuallyExclusiveConstraints to YES to have -[NSWindow visualizeConstraints:] automatically called when this happens.  And/or, break on objc_exception_throw to catch this in the debugger.
2014-01-17 17:22:58.805 UK Car Driving Theory Test Lite[14193:303] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints:
(
    "",
    "",
    ""
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint

Set the NSUserDefault NSConstraintBasedLayoutVisualizeMutuallyExclusiveConstraints to YES to have -[NSWindow visualizeConstraints:] automatically called when this happens.  And/or, break on objc_exception_throw to catch this in the debugger.
2014-01-17 17:22:58.806 UK Car Driving Theory Test Lite[14193:303] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints:
(
    "",
    "",
    ""
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint

Set the NSUserDefault NSConstraintBasedLayoutVisualizeMutuallyExclusiveConstraints to YES to have -[NSWindow visualizeConstraints:] automatically called when this happens.  And/or, break on objc_exception_throw to catch this in the debugger.
2014-01-17 17:22:58.806 UK Car Driving Theory Test Lite[14193:303] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints:
(
    "",
    "",
    ""
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint

Set the NSUserDefault NSConstraintBasedLayoutVisualizeMutuallyExclusiveConstraints to YES to have -[NSWindow visualizeConstraints:] automatically called when this happens.  And/or, break on objc_exception_throw to catch this in the debugger.
2014-01-17 17:22:58.807 UK Car Driving Theory Test Lite[14193:303] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints:
(
    "",
    "",
    ""
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint

Set the NSUserDefault NSConstraintBasedLayoutVisualizeMutuallyExclusiveConstraints to YES to have -[NSWindow visualizeConstraints:] automatically called when this happens.  And/or, break on objc_exception_throw to catch this in the debugger.

Please help..Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you ever solve the issue?